# How to set state in toggle switch with data map using react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, toggle, use-state

I am able to set state fine with data map using react hooks when i am using boolean values
I have a switch button that toggles from enabled to disabled
so `status` can be true or false...when enabled `status == true` and when disabled `status == false`

works fine below

```
        setData(data => data.map(el => el.id === postid
          ? { ...el, status: !el.status }
          : el
        ));
```

but now i want to use a string so `status` will now be using `enabled` or `disabled` values as opposed to boolean of true or false

so when `el.status == disabled` then `status == enabled` and when `el.status == enabled` then `status == disabled`

what do i do to accomplish same thing from above code?

> UPDATE:

here is how i currently get the value of `defaultChecked` for use with the toggle switch

```
<label className="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={el.status} onClick={() => updatePost(el.id, k)} />
    <span className="slider round"> </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some simple helper function which converts to string status:

```
const toStatus = (val) => val === true ? "enabled" : "disabled";
```

And then converting becomes simpler. Let me show an example:

```js
let arr = [
  {id: 1, status: false}, 
  {id: 2, status: true}, 
  {id: 3, status: false}, 
]

const toStatus = (val) => val === true ? "enabled" : "disabled";

const withStringValues = arr.map(item => ({ ...item, status: toStatus(item.status) }))
console.log(withStringValues)
```

then add a new constant to track `defaultChecked` value by converting `string` back to `boolean`

```
const toSwitch = (val) => val === "enabled" ? true : false;
```

and then update toggle switch to this

```
<label className="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={toSwitch(el.status)} onClick={() => updatePost(el.id, k)} />
    <span className="slider round"> </span>
</label>
```

Comment: so how do i handle `defaultChecked`? i updated question with information on the toggle switch defaultChecked

Comment: i tried this by adding new const to handle the value and it did not work `const toSwitch = (val) => val === false ? "disabled" : "enabled";` and then changed `defaultChecked={el.status}` to `defaultChecked={toSwitch(el.status)}` but did not work

Comment: ok fixed with `const toSwitch = (val) => val === "enabled" ? true : false;` and then changed `defaultChecked={el.status}` to `defaultChecked={toSwitch(el.status)}`...works now..thanks!!!